# Spark ML convert Map of counts to feature

Tags: feature-extraction, apache-spark-ml

I have a Scala Map of seenCounts in specific places, eg.:

```
Map(beach -> 31, cafe -> 140, prison -> 2)
```

How should I convert such type of data to features for machine learning?

Currently I construct a List[String] of items and use CountVectorizer to convert it to feature, however I am loosing information of how frequent particular place is. I would like not to loose this information.